# How to setup the application so that the users can use the parent and child forms simultaneously?

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm developing a VisualBasic 2010 application. During run-time, I've noticed that whenever the main form opens any child dialogues, forms, messageboxes, prompts etc, said main form or parent stops being accessible / clickable.

I can see the value and logic for that in most cases but there are couple of child forms that I need to use while leaving the main form still usable. I don't want to use MDI because from what I've seen, MDI forms all spawn in the same window and it's not something I'd want do.

Does anyone know if there is a way to setup the VB.net application so that the application user can use the parent and said child forms simultaneously?

Comment: Dialogs are *modal* but you can have multiple forms the user switches between (not simultaneously though - only one thing can have the input focus at a time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about Winforms (since you mentioned MDI), you have two methods to show a child form. One is `form.Show()` and the other is `form.ShowDialog()`.

`form.Show()` will leave both the parent and child forms active, and the user will be able to switch back to the parent form them without having to close the child form, while `form.ShowDialog()` will make the child form block access to the parent form until it's closed (either by the user or by the program code itself, doesn't matter).

`MessageBox.Show()` simply shows a form using `ShowDialog()`, that's why the user can't access the parent form until the messagebox is closed.

It's quite easy to create a class that will mimic the MessageBox class, only use `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()`, and thus enable the user to access both the message form and it's parent form.

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked perfectly. I was using form.showdialogue() before that.